# Activating SSL on index page of Presta Shop

Tags: ssl, prestashop

I've got problem with SSL on webpage altrak24.com. The SSL works only at admin page at address altrak24.com/admin3218/. I've tried everything including modifications of .htaccess and setting up SSL on admin page.

Any ideas how to fix this situation?

Comment: Check the hosting settings

Answer (score 0):

Best way to redirect everything is to make an url redirect rule in .htaccess (if you are on Apache) :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```